# LINQ subquery question

Tags: linq

Can anybody tell me how I would get the records in the first statement that are not in the second statement (see below)?

```
from or in TblOrganisations
where or.OrgType == 2
select or.PkOrgID
```

Second query:

```
from o in TblOrganisations
 join m in LuMetricSites
 on o.PkOrgID equals m.FkSiteID
 orderby m.SiteOrder
 select o.PkOrgID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need the whole records, or just the IDs? The IDs are easy...

```
var ids = firstQuery.Except(secondQuery);
```

EDIT: Okay, if you can't do that, you'll need something like:

```
var secondQuery = ...; // As you've already got it

var query = from or in TblOrganisations
            where or.OrgType == 2
            where !secondQuery.Contains(or.PkOrgID)
            select ...;
```

Check the SQL it produces, but I *think* it should do the right thing. Note that there's no point in performing any ordering in the second query - or even the join against TblOrganisations. In other words, you could use:

```
var query = from or in TblOrganisations
            where or.OrgType == 2
            where !LuMetricSites.Select(m => m.FkSiteID).Contains(or.PkOrgID)
            select ...;
```

Comment: Hi, I am going to need 2 fields from the first query.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need the IDs then `Except` should do the trick:

```
var inFirstButNotInSecond = first.Except(second);
```

Note that `Except` treats the two sequences as sets. This means that any duplicate elements in `first` won't be included in the results. I suspect that this won't be a problem since the name `PkOrgID` suggests a unique ID of some kind.

(See the documentation for [`Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx) and [`Queryable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.except.aspx) for more info.)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx):

```
var filtered = first.Except(second);
```